# How to record screen and save as gif animation?

Tags: screen-scraping, record, animated-gif

Is there such a software?

Comment: Apologies, but this question is not programming related, and belongs on SuperUser.com.

Comment: There probably is and you probably don't want it. Those GIFs will be huge (and ugly).

Comment: The on topic version of this same question is at SU: http://superuser.com/questions/20381/is-there-a-screen-recording-app-that-saves-as-gif

Comment: Nowaday this question could fit software reccomendations very well.. Who is so nice to reopen there with more details and deserve glory for this noble action?

Comment: [ScreenToGif](https://screentogif.codeplex.com/) does exactly that.

Comment: Try this open source GifCapture, which is written in Swift https://github.com/onmyway133/GifCapture

Comment: [ScreeToGif](https://www.screentogif.com/) has a portable version which could be used without installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this](https://github.com/dergachev/screengif) (Size -857 KB) (trial version - only 25 frames )

Answer (score 26):

Try this free tool (unlimited frames) called Cropper. Set the output as Animated Gif.

http://cropper.codeplex.com/

Update:

- In the notification area right click the cropper icon, go to Output > Animated Gif

[image]

Comment: I don't see an animated gif option. Am I missing anything?

Comment: See the screenshot in my answer

Comment: It seems the animated gif functionality is now a plugin: http://cropperplugins.codeplex.com/

Comment: For anyone using this - the produced GIF always appears to include the overlayed bounding box - which isn't ideal. This visibility doesn't appear to be configurable either.

Comment: @AlanFoster 
I found a workaround for the overlay problem. Set your crop area and record a random GIF (will be junk because overlay will be present)-> Hide cropper overlay and record another GIF using the printscreen key (prtscrn to start and prtscrn again to stop). It will record an overlay free gif using the crop setting from the last GIF recorded. The first step is needed because the crop area will only be set when you record a gif directly (using the enter key).