# Processing – What is the fastest way to generate an animated .gif-file out of Processing 2?

Tags: processing, gif

i am not shure, if there are many Processing-people inside Stackoverflow, anyway:

What is the fastest way to generate an animated .gif-file out of Processing 2?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a couple of options:

1. Use the [gifAnimation](http://extrapixel.github.io/gif-animation/) library
2. Save an image sequence from Processing, then encode a gif with an external tool (like [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php),GIMP, Photoshop, etc.)

Also check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22124039/exporting-a-gif-from-a-processing-sketch-w-gif-animation-library/22133355#22133355) for more details

Answer (score 1):

George's answer is correct if you want to do this programatically, and it's what you should do if you care about gif quality.

Another quick and dirty alternative is to capture your screen directly.

I use a tool called [ScreenToGif](http://www.screentogif.com). You can record your sketch directly, without any exporting or encoding on your end.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636011/how-to-record-screen-and-save-as-gif-animation) is another question with a bunch of similar tools.